# PHP FTP upload not working

Tags: php, upload, ftp

What I'm trying to do is automaticly upload a zip-file through FTP using PHP, and then extract the zip-file as well. However first things first: I'm having trouble with uploading the zip-file using PHP's ftp_put function. This is my script:

```
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $user, $pass); //<!--same as cPanel account user and pass?

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $user"; 
    exit; 
} else {
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $user";
}

// server & file info
$file = 'phpBB3.zip';
$ftp_root = '/public_html/';
$site_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/scripts/';

// >>>HERE<<<
// upload the file
// >>>HERE<<<
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_root .$file, $site_root . $file, FTP_BINARY);

// check upload status
if (!$upload) { 
    echo "FTP upload has failed!";
} else {
    echo "Uploaded $file to $ftp_server as $file";
}

// unzip the uploaded file (from FTP?)
$unzip = shell_exec("unzip {$file}"); //<!-- how to do this through FTP uploaded files?

// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

What's happening here is that it (SOMETIMES) uploads A PART of the file ( always the same amount; like 900 kB ) and sometimes doesn't upload anything at all. It's as if the uploading process is interrupted by the rest of the script being executed while the uploading wasn't finished yet. Though I'm not sure if that's the cause of the problem.

Though, it always gives me this error:

> Warning: ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]:
>   Connecting to port 38694 in
>   /home/quicksit/public_html/createacct.php
>   on line 93

Where the output port is always different and always larger than 20.000 ( like 30.000-50.000 ).

Could anyone help me out on this?

Thanks in advanced,
Skyfe.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a port in ftp_connect()?

Comment: Port numbers changing is normal - outgoing connections are assigned one mostly at random.

Answer (score 0):

There is a timeout and upload limit in the configuration file for PHP... you may want to check the setting there.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look into this with my host to see if that fixes it. I'll update here whether it worked.

Comment: I tried but this did not solve it. Even when I try to upload a file as small as 4kB, it takes ages and in the end it only uploaded 0kB of the file. I do get a different warning this time:

Warning: ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: PORT command successful in C:\xampp\htdocs\quicksite\test1.php on line 33

Comment: I've never used the ftp functionality of php before. I always uploaded files using the html file field and used php to move it to where it needed to be on the other end and rename it.  Do you need the ftp functionality specifically?